# Cannot resolve symbol 'Active'

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to android ,Here I need to get all column values where the Status is 'Active'.But I could not understand the formation of SQLite queries .

It is slight different from MSSQL queries.

Here is my query with the error of "cannot resolve symbol"

```
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, "WHERE ALARM_STATUS = + "Active" ");
```

please tell me where I did the mistake.

Comment: Please provide more code where you declare variables. So that we can exactly suggest you. Are you storing any Active status like key value in your database ?

Comment: Please check the updated code @JayRathodRJ

Comment: What is the *setALARM_STATUS* ? do you storing any information in DB ? if yes than what is the *KEY_NAME* you declared for that inside variable declaration part?

Comment: I have a column named ALARM_STATUS in my table and It value will be either Active or InActive ,So I trying to pass Active as a filter value @JayRathodRJ

Comment: Somewhere might be you have stored something in this *ALARM_STATUS* at a time of insert operation or whatever ? Post that query you performed for insertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
Cursor cursor= sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT ALARM_STATUS FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ALARM_STATUS= ?", new String[] {"Active"});
```

Comment: This one is even better.

Comment: It works after made a slight change like this " Cursor cursor= sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "  + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ALARM_STATUS= ?", new String[] {"Active"});"  @user2387962

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you have **3** errors in your query:

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, "WHERE ALARM_STATUS = + "Active" ");
```

Should be

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ALARM_STATUS = 'Active'");
```

---

The comma was misleading the compiler to believe you wanted to use the alternate syntax, which requires an array of parameters.

Moreover, there was a mandatory space missing before the WHERE clause.

And the rest of the query string was wrong (compare your syntax to mine).

Comment: Nice, patient and well explained answer. Congratulations and thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the appreciation.

Comment: I agree with you, my friend. Sorry if I raised troubles for you. I will stay here at your services. Thank you and best regards.